# time loop in python

Tags: python

how to performed repeated task for a definite time like for 2 hours. Means loop terminate 2 hour from start time. I have research and got start time and end time but failed to make it as iteration condition. could you please help? Or some other best way mechanism to do this?

Thanks in advance. -MKS

Comment: And the task is supposed to run as fast as it can or just every K seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from time import time, sleep
end_time = time() + x_hours * 3600 # time() is calculated in seconds

while time() < end_time:
    do_your_work()
    sleep(y_seconds)
```